# Express sum of two subspace as span of set.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V=K_n[x]$ over the field $K$ is vector space and $W_1=\{p(x): p(0)=0\}$ and $W_2=\{p(x):p(1)=0\}$ are subspaces of $V$. I had to find set $S$ such that $W_1+W_2= span(S)$.

**My attempt**: Clearly, $W_1=span\{x, x^2,...,x^n\}$ and $W_2=span\{x(x-1), x^{2}(x-1),...,x^{n-1}(x-1)\}$

if $t(x)\in W_1+W_2$
then $t(x)=p(x)+q(x)$ for some $p(x)\in W_1, q(X)\in W_2$
and hence we have, .......

$W_1+W_2=span\{x, x^2,...,x^n, x(x-1),x^{2}(x-1),...,x^{n-1}(x-1)\}$.

But clearly as $x(x-1)=x^{2}-x, x^{2}(x-1)=x^{3}-x^{2},...,x^{n-1}(x-1)=x^{n}-x^{n-1}$
and hence they are linearly dependent vectors and so we can remove it from span without affecting it.

This implies, $W_1+W_2=span\{x,x^2,...,x^n,x-1\}$

This implies $S=\{x,x^2,...,x^n,x-1\}$

**But in key**, it was given that
$S=\{x^2, x^3,...,x^n, x-1\}$ that is  $W_1+W_2=Span\{x^2, x^3,...,x^n, x-1\}$
(I know that my answer is fine because spanning set given in key and spanning set which I had find spans the same space. But still I want to know which linearly dependent vector still present in my spanning set)

In fact we can check by formula $dim(W_1+W_2)=dimW_1+dimW_2+ dim(W_1 ∩W_2)$

that $dim(W_1+W_2)=3$ so we must have some linearly dependent vector in $S$ (**which one**?)

According to key it is $x$. 
How can I remove $x$ from span? **Is $x$ is linearly dependent over others?** 
Further, is there is any easy method to solve such a problems? and can we write basis of $W_1+W_2, W_1∩W_2$  directly if we have basis of $W_1$, $W_2$

Comment: Question is updated, please help me.

Comment: By the way, if you just need to find a spanning set for $W_1 + W_2$, and you know that $S_1$ is a spanning set for $W_1$ and $S_2$ is a spanning set for $W_2$, then just uniting these spanning sets is sufficient. That is, $W_1 + W_2 = \operatorname{span}(S_1 \cup S_2)$, so you can take $S= S_1 \cup S_2$ as your spanning set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A polynomial $p(x)$ satisfies $p(0)=0$ if and only if it is divisible by $x$, so indeed
$$
W_1=\operatorname{span}\{x,x^2,\dots,x^n\}
$$
On the other hand, we have, for $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_nx^n$, $p(1)=0$ if and only if $a_0+a_1+\dots+a_n=0$. This means that $a_n=-a_0-a_1-\dots-a_{n-1}$.

Thus a basis for $W_2$ is given by the polynomials
$$
1-x^n,\quad x-x^n,\quad x^2-x^n,\quad \dots,\quad x^{n-1}-x^n
$$
which is quite different from your spanning set. Indeed,
$$
\operatorname{span}\{x(x-1),x^2(x-1),\dots,x^{n-1}(x-1)\}\subseteq W_1
$$
whereas $W_2$ is *not* a subspace of $W_1$.

You can note that $1=x^n+(1-x^n)\in W_1+W_2$; therefore $W_1+W_2=K_n[x]$ and a spanning set is obviously $\{1,x,\dots,x^n\}$.

The answer in the key is wrong.

Comment: Sir, I need to find set $S$ such that $W_1+W_2=span(S)$

Comment: Sir, no $W_2$ is not subset of $W_1$. Since $W_1=\{p(x)| p(0)=0\}$ and $W_2=\{p(x)|p(1)=0\}$ (which I doesn't mention in question)

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi I can answer what you *do* mention in the question.

Comment: Sir , so can I update my question?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi You *have* to update your question. As it stands, my answer is correct. Please, notify me when you did.

Comment: Sir question is now edited

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi Answer edited. The answer in the key is wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, for giving your valuable time & sorry for the trouble from my side.